# Saber como separar un string si hay letras iguales contiguas o si son distintas

Tags: python

Tengo un `string` que está compuesto por dos tipos de letra:

**1)** Los *bloques* (que son grupos de letras contiguas iguales).

**2)** Las *mixtas* (que son letras que no se encuentren al lado de otra igual)

Lo que trato de hacer es separar la cantidad de letras *bloque* y la
cantidad de letras *mixtas* que hay.

Por ejemplo:

1. Si mi `string` es `"BTTBZB"` se aprecia un único grupo de letras contiguas iguales, las cuales serían `'TT'`
2. Así se vería el `string` dividido en `sub strings` según el tipo de letra:

> ```
> B TT BZB # agrupado por tipo de letra
>     
> B,BZB  # Substrings de letras mixtas
>     
> TT  # Substring de letras bloque
> ```

4. Suma de letras mixtas = 4
5. Quiero saber cuantas letras mixtas hay en un `string` de forma general.

**Input del case:**

> ```
> patron_extra_0 = diferenciar_letras("BBZZTTTTZTBTBBBBZZZBBTZTBZBZZT")
> print("BBZZTTTTZTBTBBBBZZZBBTZTBZBZZT")
> print(patron_extra_0)
> print()
> ```

**el output correcto debiese ser:**

> ```
> *BBZZTTTTZTBTBBBBZZZBBTZTBZBZZT
> [11 / 19]: No cualquiera puede convertirse en un gran artista*
> ```

---

Este es el código que llevo:

```
def cocinar_ratatouille():
    import random
    string=""
    for i in range(30):
        string+=random.choice(["B","T","Z"])
    return string

def verificar_patron(ratatouille):
    #string = "BTTBZB"
    cant_mixtas = 0

    for letra, letra_siguiente in zip(ratatouille, ratatouille[1:]):
        if(letra != letra_siguiente):
            cant_mixtas += 1
    consecutivas=len(ratatouille)- cant_mixtas

    if cant_mixtas>consecutivas:
        return (f"[{cant_mixtas} / {consecutivas}]: Pronto volvere a Pucsteau... hambriento")
    elif cant_mixtas<=consecutivas:
        return (f"[{cant_mixtas} / {consecutivas}]: No cualquiera puede convertirse en un gran artista")
```

Comment: Que haz intentado hasta ahora? Podrías agregar el código que hiciste hasta ahora en la pregunta por favor?

Comment: lo hice para contar las letras consecutivas pero necesito el de las mixtas y ese no me esta resultando

Comment: Tu código está mal identado. Está así en tu programa o es por como se pegó en la pregunta?

Comment: es por cómo se pegó en la pregunta pero probé el string (que puse más arriba) y debiese salir que son 11 mixtas y con el codigo que me pasate sale que son 17, esta contando demás, ¿cómo puedo arreglar eso?

Answer (score 2):

Para lograr lo que buscas, puedes usar la función [zip](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp). Si haces `zip(cadena, cadena[1:])` te devolverá un iterable cuyo contenido será
`((letra1, letra2), (letra2, letra3), (letra3, letra4), ...)`. Esto lo puedes recorrer con un bucle [for](https://www.mclibre.org/consultar/python/lecciones/python-for.html) y [desempaquetar](https://stackabuse.com/unpacking-in-python-beyond-parallel-assignment) los items antes mencionados.

Aquí te dejo el código que creo yo hace lo que buscas:

#### Método "normal"

```
string = "BTTBZB"
cant_mixtas = 0

for letra, letra_siguiente in zip(string, string[1:]):
    # Si una letra y la letra siguiente NO son iguales, entonces la considero mixta.
    if(letra != letra_siguiente):
        cant_mixtas += 1

print(cant_mixtas)
```

#### Con comprensión de listas

```
string = "RATATOUILLE"
cant_mixtas = sum(1 for letra, letra_siguiente in zip(string, string[1:]) if(letra != letra_siguiente))
```

Siendo sincero, no estoy seguro de si esto es lo que buscas. Si no es lo que buscas, dimelo por favor...

Comment: y yo complicándome la vida :/

Comment: ahi te mandé el codigo completo es que me falla en la parte del output, añadí cuál debiese ser el output correcto de este ejercicio con ese codigo que llevo :) si me pudieras ayudar a ver qué esta fallando

Answer (score 1):

Usando expresiones regulares.

La expresión regular `r'(\w)\1+'` reconoce una letra (\w) seguida de la misma letra (\1) una o más veces (+).

El prefijo `r` (cadena en bruto) delante patrón es importante, ya que así los "" se conservan tal cual, sin ser interpretados como secuencias de escape por Python.

Usando el método `patron.sub(reemplazo, texto)` puedo reemplazar todas las ocurrencias del `patron` dentro de `texto` con `reemplazo`.

```
import re

patron = re.compile(r"(\w)\1+")
texto = "BBZZTTTTZTBTBBBBZZZBBTZTBZBZZT"
mixtas = patron.sub('', texto)
print(mixtas, len(mixtas))
```

Lo que queda después del reemplazo son las letras mixtas. El largo es el número de letras mixtas.

produce:

```
ZTBTTZTBZBT 11
```

Answer (score 0):

El principal problema es identificar los patrones iguales o mixtos. Lo primero que podemos hacer es usar `groupby()` para identificar los grupos de forma secuencial:

```
from itertools import groupby

cadena = "BBZZTTTTZTBTBBBBZZZBBTZTBZBZZT"
patrones = [''.join(g) for _, g in groupby(cadena)]

print(patrones)
['BB', 'ZZ', 'TTTT', 'Z', 'T', 'B', 'T', 'BBBB', 'ZZZ', 'BB', 
 'T', 'Z', 'T', 'B', 'Z', 'B', 'ZZ', 'T']
```

---

Con el código anterior hemos identificado fácilmente al menos los patrones "iguales", las cadenas de longitud mayor a 1, nos faltaría identificar los "mixtos", que en realidad no es más que concatenar las letras de longitud 1.

```
def obtener_patrones(cadena):

  from itertools import groupby
  patrones = [''.join(g) for _, g in groupby(cadena)]

  grupos = []
  grupo = ""

  for pat in patrones:
    if len(pat) == 1:
      grupo = grupo + pat
    else:
      if grupo:
        grupos.append((grupo, "M"))
        grupo = ""
      grupos.append((pat, "I"))

  if grupo:
    grupos.append((grupo, "M"))

  return grupos
```

---

La lógica es simple, recorremos la lista de patrones, si la cadena tiene longitud 1 la vamos concatenando hasta completar el grupo. La función finalmente nos retorna los patrones identificados:

```
cadena = "BBZZTTTTZTBTBBBBZZZBBTZTBZBZZT"
patrones = obtener_patrones(cadena)

print(patrones) 
[('BB', 'I'), ('ZZ', 'I'), ('TTTT', 'I'), ('ZTBT', 'M'), ('BBBB', 'I'), ('ZZZ', 'I'), 
 ('BB', 'I'), ('TZTBZB', 'M'), ('ZZ', 'I'), ('T', 'M')]
```

---

Con esto, tenemos cada patrón de la cadena, identificado con una `M` por mixto y `I` por igual. Ahora es sencillo contar las cantidades:

```
mixtas = len("".join([e[0] for e in patrones if e[1] == "M"]))
iguales = len("".join([e[0] for e in patrones if e[1] == "I"]))
11 19
```